# Resource Factory of Angular and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-resource

I am calling resources from a ASP.MVC page `http://host/Project/Index.cshtml` to `http://host/odata/ProjectAPI` and so on.

Angular Factory works fine with first two functions getProject and postProject and send request to `http://host/odata/ProjectAPI(:projectId value)` and `http://host/odata/ProjectAPI` consequently.

But for some unknown reasons getMembers and postMember methods are sending request to `http://host/Project/..odata/ProjectAPI(:projectId)/Members`  and `http://host/Project/..odata/MemberAPI`
Could anyone explain? PS: this requests are sent from same page but different tabs

```
app.factory('resourceProject', function ($resource) {

    return {

        getProject: function () {

            return $resource('../odata/ProjectAPI(:projectId)', { projectId: '@id' });
        },
        postProject: function () {

            return $resource('../odata/ProjectAPI');

        },
        getMembers: function () {
            return $resource('..odata/ProjectAPI(:projectId)/Members', { projectId: '@id' });

        },
        postMember: function () {
            return $resource('..odata/MemberAPI');

        }

    }


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL's are wrong:

`return $resource('..odata/ProjectAPI(:projectId)/Members'`

`return $resource('..odata/MemberAPI');`

You've put .. instead of ../

Comment: Thank you. How I couldn't notice it :D.